# Почему возникает ошибка «System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException»?

Tags: c#

Почему возникает ошибка «System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException»?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы наверное хотите вместо `Console.Read()` использовать `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: т.е до пятидесяти одной цифры?

Comment: @BadCats значение `k` на картинке `51`

Comment: Но если я не могу использовать Round для округления - как мне быть тогда? Я имею ввиду по условию - k может быть больше 15, что не как не подходит для Round

Comment: @BadCats по какому условию? Может быть стоит объяснить, чего Вы хотите добиться? Округление типа `double` более чем до 15 цифр не имеет смысла. Для `Decimal` - 28: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

округление до пятидесяти одной цифры? (значение `k` на картинке `51`)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx -

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException - digits is less than 0 or greater than 15.
>
> (количество цифр меньше 0 или больше 15)

Answer (score 0):

В методе Math.Round второе число означает количество разрядов (цифр после запятой), до которых надо округлить число. У этого метода оно может быть только от одного до пятнадцати.
Как я вижу, ответ вводится через консоль, так что тебе нужно использовать catch{} и try{},чтобы предотвратить введение пользователем нежелательной цифры.